# Bokeh - Update Div text during callback

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

**Background:**

I have a bokeh server showing a scatter plot and a DataTable. When a user clicks a data point on the plot the DataTable updates with data related to that point. Above the DataTable I have a Div with a title for the table.

I have an `ColumnDataSource.selected.on_change` with a an event handler on the source for the scatter plot and can update the DataTable.

**Issue:**

I would like to update the Div with the selected point to show what the data in the table relates to but cannot.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

src = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(tools='tap')

p.circle(x='a', y='b', source=src)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[], 'b':[]})

srcTab = ColumnDataSource(df1)

table_cols = [TableColumn(field='a', title='a'),
        TableColumn(field='b', title='b')]

dataTable = DataTable(source=srcTab, columns=table_cols)

# This is the div in question
div = Div(text="<b>Select a data point</b>")

grid = gridplot([[None, div], [p, dataTable]])

def callback(attr, old, new):
    selected_index = src.selected.indices[0] + 1

    newDf1 = df.iloc[0:selected_index,:]

    newSrcTab = ColumnDataSource(newDf1)

    srcTab.data.update(newSrcTab.data)

    # Set div text to f"Point selected: {selected_index}"

src.selected.on_change('indices', callback)

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

**Requirements:**

bokeh, pandas

The server can be started with `bokeh serve --show [folder with the above code in it]/`

**Notes:**

1. I know the event handler throws a lot of errors. This is just
   example code and not my actual use case (which has error handling).
2. I would rather do this all in python but if there is a simple solution with a CustomJS callback that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried just using `div.text = f"Point selected: {selected_index}"`?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov I thought I tried that but I guess not. It worked. Thanks.